# Cartthrob order status update notification not triggered if order status updated via Order manager

Tags: cartthrob, notification

I've been puzzling over why a Cartthrob order notification isn't being sent when an order's status is manually updated from "processing" to "completed"

The order was being updated via the CartThrob Order Manager.

I have just discovered that if I update the order entry through EE's native entry manager then the notification is triggered.

Has anyone run into this? I'm assuming the necessary hooks aren't being called when this is done via the Order Manager.

Is there a way I can fix this?

Looks like others are having the same issue http://cartthrob.com/forums/viewthread/9771/

Comment: I've also just run into this and can't figure out how to get support. Have you had any luck?

Comment: Nope, it's broken and I've not chased it up with support. I just worked around it for the time-being.

Comment: Is this still the case in the latest 2.5 update?

Comment: Confirmed, still an issue in the 2.5 update.